# Make LLVM inline a function from a library

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, inlining

I am trying to make `LLVM` inline a function from a library.

I have LLVM bitcode files (manually generated) that I linked together with `llvm-link`, and I also have a library (written in C) compiled into bitcode by `clang` and archived with `llvm-ar`. I manage to link everything together and to execute but I can't manage to get `LLVM` to inline a function from the library. Any clue about how this should be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you link the bitcode files together with the library, do you run an Internalize pass on the linked bitcode? The internalize pass makes all functions (besides `main()`) static and tells optimizer/code generator that the functions can be safely inlined without keeping a copy available for some (non-existent) external reference.

I manually link my bitcode files and bitcode libraries together using code borrowed from `llvm-ld` and I do the internalize pass, but I'm not sure if `llvm-link` does the internalize pass or not.

Comment: How can I start a internalize pass ?

Comment: @osgx: look at `createInternalizePass` (`lib/Transforms/IPO/Internalize.cpp`).